# Are docker containers safe enough to run third-party untrusted containers side-by-side with production system?

Tags: docker, microservices

We plan to allow execution of third-party micro-services code on our infrastructure interacting with our api. 
Is dockerizing safe enough? Are there solutions for tracking resources(network, ram,cpu)container consumes?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [**portainer.io**](https://portainer.io/) (see [its demo](http://demo.portainer.io), password `tryportainer`)

But to truly isolate those third-party micro-services, you could run them in their own VM defined on your infrastructure.  That VM would  run a docker daemon and services. As long as the VM has access to the API, those micro-services containers will do fine, and won't lead/have access to anything directly from the infrastructure.
You need to define/size your VM correctly to allocate enough resources for the containers to run, each one assuring their own [resource isolation](http://doger.io/).

Answer (score 2):

Docker (17.03) is a great tool to secure isolate processes. It uses **Kernel namespaces**, **Control groups** and some **kernel capabilities** in order to isolate processes that run in different containers.

But, those processes are not 100% isolated from each other because they **use the same kernel** resources. Every dockerize process that make an IO call will leave for that period of time its isolated environment and will enter a shared environment, the kernel. Although you can set limits per container, like how much processor or how much RAM it may use you cannot set limits on *all* kernel resources.

You can read [this article](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/docker-security) for more information.